# value pair is already existing in the list if not add the value pair to the list in python

Tags: python

I have a list called `my_list`. `my_list` looks like below

```
my_list = ['apple','orange','pineapple','orange','banana']
```

Here what I have to do is take the first element of the list and take the next element and create a pair for example it can be either in dict or tuple ie `[(apple,orange),(apple,pineapple),(apple,banana)]`. If the pair already exists it should not create the new one. How can I do it with python?
I tried this

```
my_new_list=[]
for i,value in enumerate(my_list):
    for j,second in enumerate(my_list):
        if ([value[i],second[j]) in my_new_list:
            pass
        else:
            my_new_list.append([value[i],second[j])
```

I am getting an error. How should I do it?

Comment: What is the error? Please [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: You could use itertools.product and thus make every single pair combination possible (no duplicates in the process).

Comment: Also, does order matter? Do you want the list to include both `('apple', 'orange')` and `('orange', 'apple')`? And what about pairs like `('apple', 'apple')`? Are these allowed?

Comment: No (apple,apple) and (orange,apple) are not allowed

Comment: I am getting syntax error near if ([value[i],second[j]) in my_new_list:

Comment: @Sherlock The syntax error is because you have `[` with no matching `]`. You have the same problem on the last line. You can remove this spurious `[` to solve the error. However, I believe you are making things much more complicated than necessary. The `if` isn't needed. See my answer below.

Comment: @Sherlock For future reference, you should include the full error message in your questions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations` along with a `set` https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

`combinations` will gives you all the combinations of a given length from the given sequence. You want pairs, so the input length will be `2`

The set solves any issues you'll get with duplicates: `('apple','apple)` or `('orange','apple')` and `('apple','orange')` won't appear.

```
import itertools

my_list = ['apple','orange','pineapple','orange','banana']
my_set = set(my_list)
my_combinations = list(intertools.combinations(my_set, 2))
```

Comment: I am getting object as the output here

Comment: You can cast `my_combinations` to a list if you want: `list(my_combinations)`

Answer (score 1):

It is always best to do the task directly. In this case, you only need to iterate over each list and append the pair to your new list. There is no need for `enumerate()` to get an index. There is no need of an if statement.
:

```
my_new_list=[]
for first in my_list:
    for second in my_list:
        my_new_list.append((first, second))
```

This is guaranteed to never create any duplicated pairs, as long as `my_list` doesn't have any duplicates. If `my_list` could have duplicates, you should remove them first. One way to do this is with `set`:

```
my_new_list=[]
for first in set(my_list):
    for second in my_list:
        my_new_list.append((first, second))
```

If the order of the resulting pairs doesn't matter and you can't have both `('apple', 'orange')` and `('orange', 'apple')` in your final list, then the innter loop should only iterate over part of the list:

```
my_new_list=[]
no_duplicates = list(set(my_list))
for i, first in enumerate(no_duplicates):
    for second in my_list[i+1:]:
        my_new_list.append((first, second))
```

The `my_list[i+1:]` syntax is called a "slice". This says to get the rest of the elements starting at index `i+1`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to closed a couple of brackets, and you don't need to index the strings:

```
my_list = ['apple','orange','pineapple','orange','banana']

my_new_list=[]

for i,value in enumerate(my_list):
    for j,second in enumerate(my_list):
        if [value,second] in my_new_list:
            pass
        else:
            my_new_list.append([value,second])
            
print(my_new_list)
```

Output:

```
[['apple', 'apple'], ['apple', 'orange'], ['apple', 'pineapple'], ['apple', 'banana'], ['orange', 'apple'], ['orange', 'orange'], ['orange', 'pineapple'], ['orange', 'banana'], ['pineapple', 'apple'], ['pineapple', 'orange'], ['pineapple', 'pineapple'], ['pineapple', 'banana'], ['banana', 'apple'], ['banana', 'orange'], ['banana', 'pineapple'], ['banana', 'banana']]
```

Comment: @Jonas Thanks, I fixed it.